# почему нельзя использовать тег usemap если img обернут в тег a или тег button?

Tags: html, html5

Почему нельзя использовать тег `usemap` если `img` обернут в тег `a` или тег `button`?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что нельзя?

Comment: @Grundy w3c говорит, что нельзя

Comment: @InDevX, может ссылку?

Comment: @Grundy я на w3c validator накидал пару строк кода и прочитал ошибку, можете сами попробовать

Answer (score 0):

Потому что нельзя вкладывать интерактивные элементы друг в друга.
Непонятно, какой из них должен отработать.

Впрочем, есть хак с обёртыванием в `<object>`, чтобы создать отдельный контекст.

А что касается вкладывания в `<button>` - это вообще плохая идея, т. к. некоторые браузеры вообще не умеют обрабатывать клики по элементам внутри button.